# UiTextView drag selected text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview

I want to select some specific text from `UITextView` and I want to drag that selected text on the screen. I have the text that I select from `UITextView`

```
(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {

if (textView.tag==1) {
   selectedRange = [self.myTextView selectedRange];
    NSRange range = [self.myTextView selectedRange];
    NSString *str = [self.myTextView.text substringWithRange:range];

    NSString *newString = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                            [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                           componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    self.calculatorDisplay.text = newString;


}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Get event when user touches inside textview (You can get that by UITextView's Delegate (startEditing delegate))

Step 2. Add a UILabel on ur view giving position where user touches in textview and giving text as that of textview and giving clear color as backgroundcolor. (Do this inside delegate of textview)

Step 3. Inside touches move of ur view change the positions of ur label dynamically according to touches.

Step 4. When user moves its touches till dropping textview delegate will be called check there if(textview==droppingtextview) then put draggingtextview.text=label.text. and remove label from superview.